# Apostrophy and quotation marks won't add to mysql from a form

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, character, reserved

I need some help here!

I have a form on a site admin page, the owner fills in his projects and the get added to a mysql db, but sometimes the data contains single or double quotes so it won't add to the db.

I tried using addslashes but it still wont work.

Heres my code which Ive tried

```
$atitle = addslashes($_REQUEST['atitle']); 
$acontent = addslashes($_REQUEST['acontent']); 

$query = "INSERT INTO projects VALUES (NULL, '$atitle', '$acontent', '$remote_file',     '$remote_file1', '$remote_file2')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if(!$result){
     $error = 'An error occured: '. mysql_error().'<br />';
     $error.= 'Query was: '.$query;
     echo $error;
     die($message);
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use preg_replace to replace the symbols with their entity, and print it out back from the db

Answer (score 0):

you can try `stripslashes()` to un-quotes a quoted string. More details are available on the PHP documentation website [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: @Joe OK. Thanks for your comment. Will do this from my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query is part of an outdated php library that isn't supported anymore.  The more reliable method of interacting with a database is mysqli.  Using mysqli, you'll be able to use Prepared Statements.  Prepared Statements are a way to validate input and to mitigate problems like this (your input having quotation ticks/marks).  Take a look at this example:

```
$db = new mysqli("host","user","pw","database");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO projects VALUES (NULL, '?', '?', '?', '?','?')");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $atitle); // s means string in the first param
$stmt->bind_param('s', $acontent); // s means string in the first param    
... // same for all other parameters in your query
$stmt->execute();
```

More on this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

I heavily recommend using mysqli.  It is current and supported.  Prepared Statements are the best way to defend against SQL injections and also catching trip-ups like this.  It will sanitize the input for you and account for quotation symbols.